# Not a single-group group function on a case count in oracle

Tags: oracle, count, group-by, case

I'm trying to adapt a query that works in MSSQL to Oracle, the query is much bigger (this part is just a field from a much bigger query) but I managed to reduce it so it looks simpler.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN COUNT(*) 
        ELSE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2)
        END
FROM table1
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
ora-00937 not a single-group group function
```

Can someone tell me where's the problem or how can I redefine it?

Comment: You are missing the group by

Comment: I don't think so as the subquery: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2
Runs fine.
Also I don't know what fields should I group by as I'm already aggregating with the Count(*)

Comment: You need group by only in the second query but it will be probably no sense query :) I will write you 1 possible solution in the aswer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1) > 0 then (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1)
       ELSE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2)
       END
FROM dual;
```

It is still ugly but it works :)

**Update:**

To explain how it's working:

We have 2 cases:

1. If there are records in the table1 then show me how many records
   there are
2. If the table1 is empty, then give me the number of records from the
   table2

Dual is the dummy table.

Comment: Although it works perfectly fine for the author of the question it would be awesome if you could explain why it works. I'm having the same problem but can't understand your solution (why it works). It would certainly help if there was any comment regarding why it works.

Comment: @Thedude I updated the answer. I hope that it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that NikNik answer is cleaner but another solution would be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT CASE 
                 WHEN Count(*) > 0 THEN Count(*) 
                 ELSE (SELECT Count(*) 
                       FROM   table2) 
               END 
        FROM   table1 
        GROUP  BY table1.primarykey1, 
                  table1.primarykey2) 
WHERE  ROWNUM = 1
```